# Process pcm wav streams in .net

Tags: c#, .net, audio, wav, pcm

I need process wave (wav) files uncompressed (pcm). As input i receive a wav in a stream (System.IO.Stream). I need do a few things:

- Get a new sound (wav) from a snippet of a other sound (wav) (by snippet i mean fragment of time)
- Join few fragments of sound (short wav) in one.
- speed up or slow a wav.

Anyone know a api, toolkit, library, dll, or anything capable to do that in .net (preference in C#)?

Answer (score 0):

Check out NAudio.  It supports PCM WAV playback and recording, and I'm sure you could accomplish what you need with it, but it will probably take some work.

http://naudio.codeplex.com

I believe another API to look at would be Bass Audio Library.  I've never used it before, but I've read good things about it:

http://www.un4seen.com/